# Masstransit MultiBus entity name formaters

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using MultiBus with two buses. Both are configured with the same RabbitMQ, but they have different EntityNameFormatters.

When I try to publish a message, the same EntityNameFormatter is used on both buses (from the bus that was registered last).

How can I fix this?